# How to use powershell to return all exchange distribution groups for a user

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm trying to pull a list of Office365 distribution groups for a specific user using powershell.  The following works when I type out (or paste)the captured $DN for the user, but if I capture the $DN and use it as a variable, I cannot get the correct results.

This works:

```
$mailbox=get-Mailbox user@domain.com
$DN=$mailbox.DistinguishedName
$DLs=Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {Members -like "CN=Lastname\, First M,OU=domain.onmicrosoft.com,OU=Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations,DC=NAMPR02A003,DC=prod,DC=outlook,DC=com"}
```

These do not:

```
$DLs=Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {Members -like $DN}
$DLs=Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {Members -like '$DN'}
$DLs=Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter {Members -like "$DN"}
```

Can anybody tell me how to get a variable for $DN to work in the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what you need:

```
$Mailbox=get-Mailbox user@domain.com
$DN=$mailbox.DistinguishedName
$Filter = "Members -like ""$DN"""
Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter $Filter
```

`Get-DistributionGroup` are not recognize/expand the filter when it's in a {ScriptBlock}

You should create a `$Filter` Variable that is not in a `{ScriptBlock}` but it's inside a `"Quotes"` from the outside and `""DoubleQuotes""` inside for the variable to expand.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you Avshalom.  I massaged that script for hours but never thought to head that direction.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

`Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited -Filter "Members -like ""$((get-Mailbox NT_ID).DistinguishedName)""" | sort name`

Answer (score -1):

Avshalom thanks for this awesome script.

I have added this to clean up the results.  Just replace "Domain" with your company's domain.

```
| Select-Object Name, @{label='PrimarySmtpAddress';expression={$_.PrimarySmtpAddress -replace '@domain.com'}}
```

Note: the -filter {Members...} may be broken in the get-distributiongroup command.  Doesn't seem to accept Members as a filterable property.  :(